# Run Kohana framework+php script in linux command prompt

Tags: php, kohana

We have a ubuntu server where we dump our  Kohana framework+php code & want to run it through cron job. But when we try it in command line it shows the following error:

```
root@andola-dev:~#  php /var/www/realradius/index.php /var/www/realradius/system/core/Bootstrap.php

Warning: require(/root/system/core/Bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/realradius/index.php on line 139

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/root/system/core/Bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/realradius/index.php on line 139
```

Comment: What are the permissions on `/root/system/core/Bootstrap.php` and every directory in the path?

Comment: Where is your `system` directory and what is a SYSPATH constant value?

Comment: I am assuming you are using Kohana 3. It is strange seeing Bootstrap.php with a capital letter as in Kohaha all filenames are lower case. Did you modify the index.php?

Comment: @gimpe it seems he's actually supplying it as "Bootstrap.php" as an argument to the php executable.

Answer (score 0):

Linux filesystems are case sensitive, windows ones are not. `Bootstrap.php` is usually lowercase. Try fixing that.